# Add a character after random numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file where I need to replace a letter after some random numbers.

Example:

```
0000006/00
...
0000018/00
```

I need it to be like: `0000006//00`, `0000018//00`

I can mark numbers before "/" with command:

`^[0-9]+`

But what is the correct command for replacing? I just wanna add extra slash after a slash :)

Comment: Find `[0-9]+/` and replace by `$1/`

Comment: You can use a regular expresion to for example replace all non-alphanumeric characters with commas:

s = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9A-Za-z]/", ",");

Note: The / after the set will make it replace each group of non-alphanumeric characters with a comma. If you want to replace each character with a comma, just remove the /.
Instead of comma you can use your own character or symbol.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to replace or non-alphas (in this case "/") because there is some "/"-characters that I want to retain. "/" which I want to "double" is always in column 7 so I tried `^[0-9](.{7})` and replace it with $1/ but this will remove the first column so the text is like: "000006//00" when it should be "0000006//00" | cmd find `0-9+/` and replace `$1/` only removes everything before "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
$str =~ s/(^[0-9]+\/)/$1\//;
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more closely what I need to do. I'm pretty newb with this stuff.

Comment: I figured it out myself: Find `(^[0-9]+\/)` -> Replace `$1\/` Thank you!